# Mapping inputs to outputs in callback of dash by plotly

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Right now, I have code to display a graph where one can give a range for both x and y values.

[This is what my output currently is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLVn5.png) Now, I want to include a button that has another input to redirect to a new page.

Is it possible to do that? As the documentation has only either multiple inputs or multiple outputs, not both.

This is my @callback code:

```
@callback(
    Output('main', 'figure'),
    Input('minNodes', 'value'),
    Input('maxNodes', 'value'),
    Input('minEdges', 'value'),
    Input('maxEdges', 'value'),
)
```

Comment: You _can_ have both multiple inputs and multiple outputs. I'm not sure to understand what you are trying to do, "_I want to include a button that has another input to redirect to a new page_", maybe with `dcc.Location()` component ? see [Redirect to a url in dash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75725718/2529954)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely pass multiple inputs and outputs both in a single callback.
To redirect to new page you can add **dcc.Location** in your layout and set the *url* in callback on input button click.
If you need to distinct the output generation in your callback based on which input change, you can check the context **trigger_id** in callback.

```
from dash import ctx
from dash.dash import no_update
@callback(
    Output('main', 'figure'),
    Output('location', 'href')
    Input('btn_id', 'n_clicks'),
    Input('minNodes', 'value'),
    Input('maxNodes', 'value'),
    Input('minEdges', 'value'),
    Input('maxEdges', 'value'),
)
def redirect_to_url(btn_click,min1,max1,min2,max2):
    triggered_id = ctx.triggered_id
    if triggered_id == 'btn_id':
        url = 'https:www.google.com'
        return no_update, url
    else: # call when other inputs have changed
        # displaygraph 
        return graph(), no_update
```